# Where is he Hiding?

Tags: word, visual, language

My friend Bob is an alien, and he is evading capture by the United States government. His native alien language is one in which the letters of each word in a sentence are superimposed on each other, with each word beginning one letter to the right of the previous word. Though he is learning English, Bob often gets confused and writes in this way with the English alphabet. For example, once, when he meant to write "Hello, my name is Bob", he accidentally wrote

[image]

One day, he had to pack up and leave without warning because he was found by government agents. I was worried sick, but thankfully, he sent me a slip of paper on which he wrote the continent, country, and city in which he is living, and he did the same for the locations of two of his alien friends. However, due to his anxiety, he accidentally made the same mistake and wrote the English words on top of each other like he would have done in his native language. Here are the locations:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Where are Bob and his two alien friends?

Comment: cool concept! :)

Comment: @thecoder16 Well thank you very much!

Comment: Nice try, Government agents!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First:

> Africa, Egypt, Giza

Second:

> Europe, Croatia, Rijeka

Third:

> America, Peru, Piura

Comment: ah, well done. i don't know that city for the third one.

Comment: @thecoder16 I'll admit I didn't either, I had to look at a [list of Peruvian cities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cities_in_Peru) :P

Answer (score 3):

Partial.

The second one:

> Europe, Croatia, Rijeka

The third one(partial):

> America, Peru, but I can't figure out the city.